# undefined reference to OOLUA::Proxy_class<T>::class_name

Tags: c++, lua, compiler-errors, oolua

I am using OOLUA 2.0.0 and am receiving the error `undefined reference to OOLUA::Proxy_class<TestClass>::class_name`.

The code is:

```
class TestClass
{
    int test_member;

    public:
        void setTestMember(int x) { test_member = x; }
        int getTestMember() { return test_member; }
 };

OOLUA_PROXY(TestClass)
    OOLUA_MEM_FUNC(void, setTestMember, int)
    OOLUA_MEM_FUNC(int, getTestMember)
OOLUA_PROXY_END

int main()
{
    OOLUA::Script script;
    script.register_class<TestClass>();
    OOLUA::run_chunk(script, "local n = TestClass.new() \n n:setTestMember(42) \n print(\"test_member is: \" .. n:getTestMember()");

    return 0;
}
```

The documentation [here](https://oolua.org/docs/_o_o_lua_proxying.html) does not appear to say anything about this error. I'm not sure what `class_name` even is. Any help is appreciated.

By the way, I'm using GCC 4.9.2 to compile it.

Comment: I don't know OOLUA but I guess that `class_name` hides in the `OOLUA_PROXY` macro.

Answer (score 1):

So this is late but hopefully it will help if anyone else runs across a similar issue. Basically your example is missing an important but subtle part that will help explain why you got the link errors you got.

*TestClass.hpp*

```
class TestClass
{
    int test_member;
public:
    void setTestMember(int x) { test_member = x; }
    int getTestMember() const { return test_member; }
    static void aStaticMember() { }
};

OOLUA_PROXY(TestClass)
OOLUA_MEM_FUNC(void, setTestMember, int)
OOLUA_MEM_FUNC_CONST(int, getTestMember)
OOLUA_SFUNC(aStaticMember)
OOLUA_PROXY_END
```

*TestClass.cpp*

```
OOLUA_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS(TestClass
    ,setTestMember
)
OOLUA_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS_CONST(TestClass
    ,getTestMember
)
```

You must always put a `OOLUA_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS` block in the associated .cpp file so that the declarations from the `OOLUA_PROXY` block are defined. Even if you only have const member functions, you must still place an empty block e.g. `OOLUA_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS(TestClass)` in the .cpp file. In the event that your class only has static functions, you would be required to use a slightly different setup.

In summary:

- `OOLUA_PROXY` declares a proxy class
- `OOLUA_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS` blocks define the members of that class

Also, if your class has only static member functions exposed, you will need to include a `OOLUA_EXPORT_NO_FUNCTIONS(TestClass)` in the .cpp file. For every static member you must then use special syntax for registering the static functions with the Script.

```
using namespace OOLUA; //NOLINT(build/namespaces)
Script vm;
vm.register_class_static<TestClass>("aStaticMember",
    &OOLUA::Proxy_class<TestClass>::aStaticMember);
```

The documentation is not very helpful in this matter, but if you reveiw the associated test source files, they in combination with the documentation are enough to get past most issues.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better posting questions about the library to the mailing list oolua.org/mailinglist

Have a look at the documentation for the library, specifically exporting class functions[1]. Personally I would use the minimalist DSL for your functions instead of the expressive, this would then make your proxied functions like the following (however the get should really be a constant function):

```
OOLUA_MFUNC(setTestMember)
OOLUA_MFUNC(getTestMember)
```

[1] https://docs.oolua.org/_o_o_lua_proxying.html